# no suitable user-defined conversion, but the convertion is specified

Tags: c++, iterator, const-iterator

I am coding a vector class with iterators for a school exercice.
I am getting the following error and I don't know how to go about it:

*'no suitable user-defined conversion from "vectorIterator" to "vectorIterator<**const** int>" exists'*

This is the code I am trying to execute:

```
vector<int> v;
v.push_back(1);
v.push_back(2);
vector<int>::const_iterator it = v.begin();
```

This is part of the code in my class vector:

```
template <typename T, typename Alloc = std::allocator<T> >
class vector {
..
public:
typedef vectorIterator<value_type>          iterator; 
typedef vectorIterator<const value_type>    const_iterator;
..
iterator        begin()         { return iterator(m_data); } // if commented the above code works
const_iterator  begin() const   { return const_iterator(m_data); }
..
}
```

If I comment the first form of begin() the code compiles and runs ok, so it seems that it obscures the const form.
I would expect the compiler to know to use the const form of begin(), but it does not.
What am I missing?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Where/How is `value_type` defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `vectorIterator` is a template class, which means that `vectorIterator<int>` and `vectorIterator<const int>` are *two* different types, they can *not* be converted to each other. You need to add a conversion constructor for `vectorIterator<const int>` that accepts `vectorIterator<int>`, using template should be enough (some constraints on `U` are omitted here for simplicity):

```
template<typename T>
struct vectorIterator { 
  // ...
  template<typename U>
  vectorIterator(vectorIterator<U>);
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/YbdoM1Ws7)

Comment: You are totally right! I don't totally understand the syntaxis here though.